# How to use more times css transform property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically I want that an image change its position sometimes so I use this code:

JQUERY:

```
$(block).delay(2200).css({                
                transform: 'matrix(0.586,0.8,-0.8,0.586,40,40)'
            }).css({
                "transition-duration": "5s"
            }).delay(2200).css({                
                transform: 'matrix(0.866,0.5,-0.6,0.866,0,0)'
            }).css({
                "transition-duration": "5s"
            });
```

but after the first transform nothing changes.

How can I use more times this css property?
There is a better way to do the same effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a CSS animation, instead of JS? It'll run faster, and work for people who have JS disabled:

```
.block {
 @animation: myAnimation, 14400ms, forwards, linear;
}

@keyframes myAnimation {
  15.3% { transform: none; }
  50%   { transform: matrix(0.586,0.8,-0.8,0.586,40,40); }
  65.3% { transform: matrix(0.586,0.8,-0.8,0.586,40,40); }
  100%  { transform: matrix(0.866,0.5,-0.6,0.866,0,0); }
}
```

- Nothing happens for the first 15.3% of time (2200/14400).
- Over the next 5000ms (until the 50% mark), the first transformation unfolds.
- Nothing happens for the next 15.3% of the time.
- Over the next 5000ms (until 50%), the second transformation unfolds.

There's a great tutorial at [MDN Using CSS Animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations)

Comment: Please select it as your preferred answer, so others can see that your question was answered.

Answer (score 0):

[`delay()`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) only works for animtions, not for other stuff. You will have to use `setTimeout()`

```
setTimeout( transform_one, 2200);

function transform_one() {
  $('#block').css({ transform: 'matrix(0.586,0.8,-0.8,0.586,40,40)' }).css({ "transition-duration": "5s" });
  setTimeout( transform_two, 7200);
}

function transform_two() {
  $('#block').css({ transform: 'matrix(0.866,0.5,-0.6,0.866,0,0)' }).css({ "transition-duration": "5s" });
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h2aq3zt0/)

Note that for the second timeout there is a 7200ms delay, as the animation itself takes 5000ms. 5000ms + your 2200ms = 7200ms.